# How do I filter an audio signal that has 4 noise spikes in its Fourier transform in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, noise

I'm just a beginner in using Matlab, and my version is R2012b. We were provided, as an assignment, with an audio signal with its sampling frequency in a .mat file that I can play to see the signal (Handel's Hallelujah with constant noise). I can also use the wavwrite function to hear it outside of Matlab. Now, when I do an fft, I can see the plotted sound - with, however, 4 high spikes in the frequency spectral analysis.

I was asked to design a filter to remove the noise, and as an instruction that I should remove these spikes. How should I proceed to do this? First I've tried to set to 0 those parts of the Fourier transform that spiked, but that just distorted the signal. Then I've tried using the Filter Design toolbox to design a bandstop filter, but I didn't know how since we weren't yet introduced to it. What filter should I use and how?

Comment: What is spectral distribution of noise? Please attach plot of spectral distribution.It will help someone to tell you, what kind of filter, you can use...

Comment: This article might be helpful to you: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/matlab-how-to-design-lpf-bpf-hpf-without-builtin-functions

Answer (score 0):

Matlab have a signal toolbox that come with a GUI to build Low-pass, bandstop and high-pass filter. The command is `fdatool`. With pole/zero plot, try to figure out what the best parameter to use with bandstop. Be sure all your pole are into your filter else you'll add noise back.